# how to give a data two annotations using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations, geom-text

Here is my example:

```
a <- data.frame(X=c(1,2,3,4,5),Y=c(1,2,3,4,5),A1=c(1,2,3,4,5),A2=c(6,7,8,9,10))
```

A1 and A2 are two types of annotation. Now I only can add one annotation into the plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=a,aes(x=X,y=Y,label=A1)) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_text(hjust=0,vjust=-1)
```

Can I put A1 and A2 into the plot? So it looks like A1 and A2 are one the same vertical line, and A1 is on top of A2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different `geom_text`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(a,aes(X, Y)) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_text(aes(label = A1), ahjust = 0, vjust = -2.5) +
      geom_text(aes(label = A2), ahjust = 0, vjust = -1) +
      ylim(c(min(a$Y), max(a$Y) + 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `paste` in `label`

```
ggplot(data=a,aes(x=X,y=Y,label=paste(A1,A2, sep = ","))) + geom_point() + geom_text(hjust=0,vjust=-1)
```